Why does click only work for every other li?
I'm creating a simple to do list, when you type the todo and click submit, it adds an li to the ul. When you click on the text of the li it will put a line through the words. However, when two or more lis are appended to the ul, only every other li will respect this line-through action. Can someone point out why and solve this problem?


const ul = document.querySelector('ul')
const submitTodo = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]')
const addTodo = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]')

submitTodo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let newTodo = document.createElement('li')
  newTodo.innerText = addTodo.value

  let newTodoRemove = document.createElement('button')
  newTodoRemove.innerText = 'Remove To-do'

  ul.appendChild(newTodo)
  newTodo.appendChild(newTodoRemove)

  const allLis = document.querySelectorAll('li')
  console.log(allLis)

  for (let li of allLis) {
    li.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      if (e.target.style.textDecoration == 'line-through') {
        e.target.style.textDecoration = 'none'
      } else {
        e.target.style.textDecoration = 'line-through'
      }
    })
  }
})
<h1>To do list!</h1>
<form>
  <input type='text'>
  <input type='submit' placeholder='Add to do'>
</form>
<ul>
</ul>




Your code adds event listeners for all the <li> elements every time a single new <li> is added. When you use .addEventListener(), previously-added listeners are not removed. All of them will run one after the other when an element is clicked.

To add to the above comment. Instead of looping over all the LIs, just add an event listener to the new li. newTodo.addEventListener. Or... you could add one single event listener to the document and inside the event listener, check the event target is an LI and change the style. ie, event bubbling.

you can also use event delegation, i.e. add the click event to the UL then check the target in the handler and do what's required only when the target is appropriate

Just as the other users commented over on the comments' section, you wouldn't need to iterate through all the li elements of the ul but assign just a new event listener to the new li item.
Here is a minimal reproducible example of your code. I passed the addEventListener to every new li item that was being created whenever the user hits the submit button, and it works.


const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const submitTodo = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');
const addTodo = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]');

submitTodo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let newTodo = document.createElement('li');
  newTodo.innerText = addTodo.value;
  let newTodoRemove = document.createElement('button');
  newTodoRemove.innerText = 'Remove To-do';
  ul.appendChild(newTodo);
  newTodo.appendChild(newTodoRemove);

  newTodo.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.style.textDecoration == 'line-through') {
      e.target.style.textDecoration = 'none';
    } else {
      e.target.style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    }
  });



});
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='todo.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>To do list!</h1>
  <form>
    <input type='text'>
    <input type='submit' placeholder='Add to do'>
  </form>
  <ul>

  </ul>
  <script src='todo.js'></script>
</body>

</html>



